# Is HttpWebRequest.Abort() blocking?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I call HttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), GetResponseStream,Read  in a new thread. 
Sometimes my GUI freezes when I call Abort() from a click event.
Should I call Abort from a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft website

> The Abort method will **synchronously** execute the callback specified to
>   the BeginGetRequestStream or BeginGetResponse methods if the Abort
>   method is called while either of these operations are outstanding.
>   This can lead to potential deadlock issues.

Have you ever tried HttpWebRequest.Close();

Even if you call in another thread, the abort method is sync.

Comment: I think GetResponse() may take many seconds due to bad internet connection. I use Abort to cancel this. The problem is Abort is not immediate so I think I will call Abort also in different thread. There is no Close() method.